# C# SqlDependency - Invalid object name

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, service-broker

I want to check out SqlDependency but got problem while starting. I'm using code below (which is from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency).

Error "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name '[core].[intServiceClient_Queue]'.'" is thrown while running a method SqlDependency.Start(connString,queue).

I am connecting with SSPI on Sql Server Admin account. I am sure that object is service broker queue and it exists.

```
void Initialization()  
{  
    // Create a dependency connection.  
    SqlDependency.Start(connectionString, queueName);  
}  

void SomeMethod()  
{  
    // Assume connection is an open SqlConnection.  

    // Create a new SqlCommand object.  
    using (SqlCommand command=new SqlCommand(  
        "SELECT ShipperID, CompanyName, Phone FROM dbo.Shippers",   
        connection))  
    {  

        // Create a dependency and associate it with the SqlCommand.  
        SqlDependency dependency=new SqlDependency(command);  
        // Maintain the refence in a class member.  

        // Subscribe to the SqlDependency event.  
        dependency.OnChange+=new  
           OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);  

        // Execute the command.  
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())  
        {  
            // Process the DataReader.  
        }  
    }  
}  

// Handler method  
void OnDependencyChange(object sender,   
   SqlNotificationEventArgs e )  
{  
  // Handle the event (for example, invalidate this cache entry).  
}  

void Termination()  
{  
    // Release the dependency.  
    SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString, queueName);  
}
```

Comment: check your database to see if the object (table, stored proc, view etc..) named [core].[intServiceClient_Queue] exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug/shortcoming in `SqlDependency`: it does not support schema names. `[core].[intServiceClient_Queue]` is taken to be the name of an object and escaped, producing an invalid object name. Move your queue to the default schema of your user (most likely `dbo`), or set the default schema to `core` and schema-qualify everything else.

See

- https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlDependencyListener.cs,161
- https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlDependencyListener.cs,140
- https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlConnection.cs,1685
- https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlUtil.cs,1615

Comment: You are right. But this is odd. Before posting a question I created synonym in dbo schema and it wasn't working either.

Comment: @michałkudanowski: Hook up a profiler and see the queries generated in the background. You're bound to find something that will not work correctly with a synonym (as opposed to the base object name).